# Where should I store JS in Laravel 5?

Tags: javascript, laravel, assets, gulp, laravel-5

There are 2 places where I can store javascripts: `resources/assets/javascripts` and `public/js`.

If we put the files in `resources/assets/javascripts`, we should add gulp tasks to copy them. And this is a weakness of this method. And we will need path mapping in browser debugger.

If we put these files in `public/js`, we will have our source JS and compiled JS in one place and they will be messed up.

So, where should I store JS in Laravel 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my old question and decided to answer myself.

In 2018 it's better to split the system into many separate projects: backend, frontend, iOS app, Android app, etc.
And each app may have its own build system, directory structure, etc.

Answer (score 10):

The "Laravel-5" answer is to put them in `resources/assets/javascripts`. Then you use Laravel-Elixer, which is the new `npm` package from Taylor + Jeffrey Way that handles the entire asset management for you using gulp.

Using Laravel-Elixer, you can publish, combine, minifiy and version control all your css + js assets in a simple workflow.

Elixer does alot more - you can read about it here: https://github.com/laravel/elixir

Jeffrey Way has also done a whole Laracast series on it (which I think this series is free): https://laracasts.com/index/elixir

Comment: I use Elixir, but the problem is JS debugging. How can I add mappings to browser to make debugging as easy as having all source files in `public/js`?

Comment: Jeffrey has said that source mapping is a feature that is coming for Elixir.