# Laravel JS Files

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5.6

My question is simple, where should I store js files like bootstrap.js or my own files? 
I found out this
[Where should I store JS in Laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765551/where-should-i-store-js-in-laravel-5)

But I really don't understand how should I include it in my view to be used.

Comment: [Laravel frontend](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/frontend) and [Laravel mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix). This should get you on the right path

Comment: You put your raw LESS, SCSS, JS files in `resources/assets` and then you use a pre-processor, e.g. Webpack, Gulp, Grunt, to compile them to the `public` directory. Laravel Mix, as linked above helps streamline this process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using either of two case in your mentioned link like below

There are 2 places where I can store javascripts: resources/assets/javascripts and public/js.

If you put the files in resources/assets/javascripts, then should add gulp tasks to copy them into public/js folder so it will ultimately present into public/js folder .

2) You can directly put these files in public/js.

Then you can call it in your layout file or any blade file like this

```
<script src="{{ asset('/js/bootstrap.js') }} "></script>
```

And if you are using laravelcollective/html form then you can also do this like

```
{{ Html::script('js/bootstrap.js') }}
```

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, but now I have another one, why should I compile using gulp/elixir/mix when I store them in the resources/assets/js and not to store directly in the public/js ?

Comment: @JulianMendez it is an individual choice to compile or directly store in js. You can also directly store in public/js. Gulp/elixir/mix can uglify and compress js files and much more. So if your project use many js library then storing them in resources/assets/js and you can mix and minify those js by specifying  task file and copy into one file of public/js. It will become easy to manage. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can put it inside public/js folder
2. Then you can add it in header or footer as usual like `<script src="{{ asset('assets/js/bootstrap.js') }} " type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: #2 is incorrect. The `resources/assets/js` directory is not web accessible (if Laravel is configured properly), so this won't work.

Comment: public folder will be accessible, I have updated my answer.